# How do you link a bootloader to a c kernel and compile them to an iso?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

**Original Question: How do you write a boot loader and create an iso?**

I recently created a simple version of a kernel for the operating system I am designing. It is completed the asm and c code are linked and compiled into the kernel, but I can't figure out how to **create the boot loader** and compile it **into an iso**.

So how do you complete this seemingly simple but mysterious task? How can I write a boot loader and create an iso from the boot loader and the kernel?

Please don't give answers like "combine them" or something obvious. Explain how I would combine them.

Thanks!

**EDIT: I know how to make a simple boot loader now**

There are ***hundreds*** of simple boot loader tutorials out there, and I can adapt them in many ways I have found.

I can make the basic single stage bootloader and jump to protected mode and stuff like that, but I still don't know how to link my kernel to any kind of boot loader that I can come up with. I'd like to implement graphics now, but I can't seem to find information on having GRUB2 (which is what I have used to load my kernel) to swithc to it for me. I know how to use graphics mode without interrupts after switching (ie using memory), but I don't know how to link a graphical bootloader to my kernel (written in c NOT c++).

Really what I need now is:

**More Specific Question: How do you **link** a boot loader to a c kernel and create an iso?**

Comment: There are probably ready-made tools, but I made one tuned to my usage, using the DiscUtils library.

Comment: Don'task new questions in an old question. Create a new question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It is more of an extension to the old question than a new one, but anyway wording fixed. This change makes the question more applicable to other people, less just "how do you make this gimme code" and more "how do you apply these coding concepts."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a floppy disk image, typically 2880*512 bytes in size. This image represents a 3.5" boot floppy disk.

Then you use a tool capable of creating a bootable CD image from a bootable floppy disk image. Under Linux "mkisofs" would be such a tool. I'm sure there is a Windows port for "mkisofs", too.